# Is it possible to integrate Apple iCloud services (e.g. contacts, calendars) with Fedora 20?

Tags: calendar, icloud

I am a new laptop user after using an iMac desktop for about seven years. Over that time, I had become fairly reliant on Apple's services syncing between my iPhone and my iMac.

Now that I'm on Fedora, I'm having to run two separate calendars and contact books, and manually update changes between the two.

Is there a way I can integrate Apple's iCloud features (namely contacts and calendar) onto my laptop? It would make day-to-day computing much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no clear way to integrate a Linux desktop with iCloud services, as Apple makes it difficult for anyone who is not using an Apple machine to use their services. ;)